# In app scripts, confirm that 2 adjacent cells match, then use a directory tab to push data to a specified sheet ID

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, indexing, match

Beware, I may be overthinking this.

I keep getting into cyclic thought loops when I'm trying to figure out what to do in this situation, So I will try to explain my thinking and where I am at.

1. Form is filled out on Google Sheets
2. Form replies are added to the main Form sheet in the "form responses tab"

[image]

3. Code actives, checking to see if the form was filled correctly (columns A and B match)

[image]

4. if they match, it finds the respective google spreadsheet ID that that row needs to go to, by looking at the directory tab.

[image]

5. That item is then sent over to the appropriate list, which is in it's own sheet

[image]

6. This continues for the rest of the rows of the Main QA Forms Responses tab, until all rows have been checked and there are no more entries.

I've been trying to understand this for hours on end, but might be approaching this all from the wrong angle.
As of right now, this is how far i've gotten in the code:

```
function onEdit() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
var r = s.getActiveRange();
var columnSearchNum = 3;
var columnDatastarts = "C";

var formSheetName = "QA Form Responses";
var directorySheetName = "Program Directory";
var matchingProgramSheetIDColumn = 1;

if(s.getName() == formSheetName && r.getColumn(0) == r.getColumn(1)) {
  var sourceRow = r.getRow();
  var matchingProgram = sourceRow.getRange(0,0).getValue();

  var matchingProgramSheetID = s.getName(Programdirectory)....//[code needed1]
  //^^^^ I need a line here to pull matching the data inSheetID column where Matching program's string is
  //from this code line, Go to that 'program's sheet'


  var programSheet = ss.getSheetByID(matchingProgramSheetID);
  var programSheetNumRows = programSheet.getLastRow();
  //console.log(programSheetNumRows);
  var formSheetNumColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var targetRange = programSheet.getActiveRange()
  var targetValue = +s.getRange(columnDatastarts+sourceRow).getValue()
  //console.log(targetValue);
  var programSheetRange = programSheet.getRange(1,columnSearchNum,programSheetNumRows,1);
  //console.log(programSheetRange.getNumRows() +" " +programSheetRange.getNumColumns() + " " + programSheetRange.getValues());
  var targetRow = findIndex(programSheetRange.getValues(), targetValue);
  //console.log(targetRow);
  var target = programSheet.getRange(targetRow, 1);
  s.getRange(sourceRow, 2, 1, formSheetNumColumns).moveTo(target);
 ;
}
}

function findIndex(array, search){
  //console.log(array);
  if(search == "") return false;
  for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    //console.log("comparing " + +array[i] + " to "+ +search);
    if (+array[i] == +search){ 
      return i+1;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? And, in order to correctly understand your situation and test the script, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet?

Comment: You said _Form is filled out on Google Sheets_. Was this deliberate?  Is it possible that you meant "Form is filled out on Google Forms"? The implications of the difference between the two would be very far-reaching.

Comment: google forms, and then once the answers are placed into the sheet linked to the form, this code would fire

Comment: Have you tested the code you're using? How's that working for you? Any errors? I'd suggest you to try to focus the issue a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find a match for a value on the Form Responses sheet with values in a given column on another sheet, and then return the value in the cell adjacent to the matching cell.

There are probably many ways to do this, but the Javascript method `indexOf` is an obvious choice if using a script. The following is untested, but the logic is sound.

**Insert at [code needed1]**

```
// define the Program sheet
var progsheet = ss.getSheetByName(directorySheetName)
// define the first row of data on the program sheet
var firstRowofData = 3
// get the data for columns one and two of the program sheet.
// starting row=3, starting column=1, number of rows = lastrowminus first row plus 1, number of columns = 2
var progsheetdata = progsheet.getRange(firstRowofData,1,progsheet.getLastRow()-firstRowofData+1,2).getValues()
// get Program manager Column
var ProgManager = progsheetdata.map(function(e){return e[0];})
// search the Program manager Column for  the first instance of the matching program value
// indexOf returns index if found, or -1 if not found
var result =ProgManager.indexOf(matchingProgram);
if (result == -1){
    // couldn't find a matching program
    // do something to quit/error message
    return
}
else
{
    // the id will be in the row returned by IndexOf and in the adjacent column to the right.
    var id = progsheetdata[result][1]
}
```